# `composer require prestashop/prestashop` installs, but is missing some folders

Tags: composer-php, prestashop, prestashop-modules

I am trying to install Prestashop via `composer require prestashop/prestashop:^8` in an effort to separate my custom code from the Prestashop core code. My intention is to have only my own customisations (themes, modules with hooks) in the project folder all committed to GIT, with all the dependencies (including Prestashop itself) moved into the gitignore'd `vendor`. I should then be able to quickly update the upstream Prestashop code via composer.

The following files and folders are being created by composer in my project folder:

```
~/prestashop-composer# tree -L 1
.
├── composer.json
├── composer.lock
├── modules
├── themes
└── vendor
```

There are a few problems:

- `modules` and `themes` contain Prestashop's default modules and themes, so if I commit my project folder to GIT, I will have to version-control them, or gitignore each of them

  (This could be intended. Both `modules/*` and `themes/*/` [are in Prestashop's `.gitignore`](https://github.com/PrestaShop/PrestaShop/blob/0644ffe53481fa2b97ddc2113848147076beddb2/.gitignore). Apparently, they are supposed to be version-controlled separately from the core.)
- necessary files and folders, such as `./config`, `./js` etc., that are present in a [traditional installation](https://github.com/PrestaShop/PrestaShop/blob/0644ffe53481fa2b97ddc2113848147076beddb2/INSTALL.txt) from [a zip-file release](https://github.com/PrestaShop/PrestaShop/releases) and present on [github.com/PrestaShop/PrestaShop](https://github.com/PrestaShop/PrestaShop), are missing from my project folder

So my general question is if what I'm trying to accomplish is possible at all?

If so, how do I separate and version-control my custom code?

P.S.

- Composer-installed:

  ```
  ~/prestashop-composer# tree vendor/prestashop -d -L 1
  vendor/prestashop
  ├── circuit-breaker
  ├── decimal
  ├── laminas-code-lts
  ├── prestashop
  └── translationtools-bundle

  5 directories
  ```

  ```
  ~/prestashop-composer# tree vendor/prestashop/prestashop -L 1
  vendor/prestashop/prestashop
  ├── admin-dev
  ├── app
  ├── autoload.php
  ├── bin
  ├── cache
  ├── classes
  ├── CODE_OF_CONDUCT.md
  ├── composer.json
  ├── composer.lock
  ├── config
  ├── CONTRIBUTING.md
  ├── CONTRIBUTORS.md
  ├── controllers
  ├── docker-compose.yml
  ├── docs
  ├── download
  ├── error500.html
  ├── img
  ├── index.php
  ├── init.php
  ├── install-dev
  ├── INSTALL.txt
  ├── js
  ├── LICENSE.md
  ├── localization
  ├── mails
  ├── Makefile
  ├── modules
  ├── override
  ├── pdf
  ├── phpstan.neon.dist
  ├── README.md
  ├── src
  ├── templates
  ├── tests
  ├── themes
  ├── tools
  ├── translations
  ├── upload
  ├── var
  ├── vendor
  └── webservice

  27 directories, 15 files
  ```

  And `vendor/prestashop/prestashop` contains only `.htaccess`.
- [Traditional install](https://github.com/PrestaShop/PrestaShop/blob/0644ffe53481fa2b97ddc2113848147076beddb2/INSTALL.txt) from a [ZIP-file release](https://github.com/PrestaShop/PrestaShop/releases):

  ```
  ~/prestashop-zip# tree vendor/prestashop -d -L 1
  vendor/prestashop
  ├── autoload
  ├── circuit-breaker
  ├── decimal
  ├── laminas-code-lts
  └── translationtools-bundle

  5 directories
  ```

So what I get from composer does contain `prestashop/prestashop` as a dependency, but does not have any autoload. And what comes out of the zip-archive is the other way around.

Answer (score 0):

I'm unsure whether what you're doing is a good approach. If you want to separate your code you can create modules, as PrestaShop is a modular system.

Comment: Hi Krystian, thank you for your answer. How do I then arrange the code to where I can do `git clone my-prestashop-store-repo` followed by `composer install` and get everything up and running?

Comment: We've recently upgraded our installation guide, I highly recommend you check it :) https://devdocs.prestashop-project.org/8/basics/installation/