# Directory tree is different when installed from a ZIP archive vs. composer require. Where does composer get these instructions from?

Tags: php, composer-php

When I install Prestashop via `composer require prestashop/prestashop:^8`, I get the following structure in the folder where it happens:

```
root@localhost:prestashop-composer# tree . -L 1
.
├── composer.json
├── composer.lock
├── modules
├── themes
└── vendor
```

The rest of the Prestashop code I'm seeing on [github.com/PrestaShop/PrestaShop/tree/develop](https://github.com/PrestaShop/PrestaShop/tree/develop) goes to `vendor/prestashop/prestashop`. (Related: when I download Prestashop as a [ZIP file release](https://github.com/PrestaShop/PrestaShop/releases) the oldschool way, `vendor/prestashop/prestashop` doesn't exist there, as all of the Prestashop code is in the root.)

How does Composer make the decision to specifically put only `modules` and `themes` here, and keep the rest in `vendor`? It must be instructed by some configuration file somewhere, but I cannot find it.

Some of the things I looked at:

- checked [packagist.org/packages/prestashop/prestashop](https://packagist.org/packages/prestashop/prestashop) to confirm it indeed uses [github.com/PrestaShop/PrestaShop/tree/develop](https://github.com/PrestaShop/PrestaShop/tree/develop) as source
- [Searched](https://github.com/search?q=repo%3APrestaShop%2FPrestaShop%20packagist&type=code) Prestashop's Github for any mention of `packagist`
- Searched for how does composer decide folder structure, but only found general information

(This question is a part of [`composer require prestashop/prestashop` installs, but is missing some folders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76683022/composer-require-prestashop-prestashop-installs-but-is-missing-some-folders))

Answer (score 1):

If you want to install Prestashop as a project using composer all you have to do is `composer create-project prestashop/prestashop` in your project directory.

What `composer require prestashop/prestashop:^8` actually does is to simply install Prestashop v8+ as a dependency for the current project you're working on and I think that is not what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Thank you! This is the answer I was looking for 
in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76683022/composer-require-prestashop-prestashop-installs-but-is-missing-some-folders, can you please post it there and delete it from here? I will try this and get back to you

Comment: Alright, I'll do that